# VS2013 Express ignores indentation inside the multiline comment of the C++ code snippet

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets, code-formatting, visual-studio-express

I am having the next C++ code snippet for Visual Studio 2013 Express. It does not contain any code and represents an indented multiline code comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>fileComment</Title>
            <Shortcut>fileComment</Shortcut>
            <Description>Creates a comment for a C++ file</Description>
            <Author>Podskal</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>fileName</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The name of the file.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>header.h</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>description</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The desription for the file.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>File with definitions and declarations.</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="cpp">
<![CDATA[
/*
File:
    $fileName$
Description:
    $description$
*/$end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

While inserting it I have encountered that VS skips all the code indentations inside the multiline comment, resulting not 
in

```
/*
File:
    header.h
Description:
    File with definitions and declarations.
*/
```

but in

```
/*
File:
header.h
Description:
File with definitions and declarations.
*/
```

What could possibly cause such a behaviour and what could be done to rectify it?

What have been tried:

- Replicated the same snippet for C# ( `<Code Language="CSharp">` ) - snippet inserts correctly in C# files;
- Replaced tab characters with spaces inside the CODE block - no result;
- Changed settings in    Tools->Options->C\C++->Tabs - no result;
- Changed few settings in    Tools->Options->C\C++->Advanced and Tools->Options->C\C++->Formatting - no result.

Comment: Mostly because it is impossible to keep everybody happy.  If they'd keep indentation then somebody else is going to complain that it changes when they use Edit + Advanced + Format Document.  So best to keep everybody equally unhappy.  Use // instead.

Comment: Well, I agree that it is impossible to make everyone happy, but why have they made the behaviour different for C# and C++ snippets? It just doesn't make sense.